# Safe way to kill thread inside action handler

Tags: c, linux, pthreads, posix

I'm developing a C99 multi-threaded Linux program, and I have several threads that run third party code. So, I want to be able to handle **SIGSEGV** in order to exit the problematic thread and give other threads the chance to finish nicelly and, finally, exit the program. The problem is that pthread_exit is not async-signal-safe and I'm wondering what is the correct way to do that.

I don't care about portabillity since it works on Linux 3.0+.

**Edit**: Sorry I did write pthread_kill but I really meant pthread_exit, since pthread_kill will just send another signal.

**Update** Following the feedback of Damon:

What I mean with finish nicely is to wait the other threads finish their processing. And then quit the whole process. Setting a global (static volatile sig_atomic_t g_quit). But, at the same time, I don't want that the thread that generated the SIGSEGV continue its processing.

Comment: The important question is what "finish nicely" means for you. If this means "free memory, exit without crashing", you can just as well kill them all, the result is the same. If, on the other hand, it means "finish some processing, and save result to disk", there exists no single good solution other than setting a global flag (shared memory location, or an eventfd that you can poll, whatever) which threads will _check_ at defined intervals, and go into save-shutdown-exit mode then. Killing or cancelling threads will never be acceptable in such a situation. Even if you cancel a thread, which...

Comment: ... which is somewhat less brutal than killing it, then it will exit in a "somewhat controlled" way at the next cancellation point. But what if it's still not the good time? What if the thread needs to do 2 calls to `write`? The first one will be the cancellation point, and the thread will be gone, with half-saved data on disk. (About being async-safe, you can work around this for example by blocking another thread on `poll` or `read` on some file descriptor (eventfd?), and writing to it in your signal handler, `write` being async-signal-safe)

Comment: What I mean with finish nicely is to wait they finish their processing. A then quit the whole process. Setting a global (static volatile sig_atomic_t g_quit). But, at the same time, I don't want that the thread that generated the SIGSEGV continue its processing.

Comment: Well, then just set the global, remove the signal handler, and return from your handler. The reason for the SIGSEGV will not have magically disappeared, so it will fire again, and kill the process.

Comment: If what you want is to blocking the thread that has segv instead of exiting the process, would blocking it simply work?  Just let it pause?

Comment: Well, if I just clean the handler and let it break again as suggested by Damon, there will be 2 problems: I will cannot be sure if the other threads had finished when it break again and I will let a crazy thread continue, what is bad.

If I block the thread, as suggested by tristan, the problem will be that I will possibly run on a dead lock, since another thread can mess up too.